# Google App Engine connect external MySQL Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-app-engine

How could connect to external MySQL server? On my localhost it can connect the server over the internet fine. However once deploy to google app engine, it fail to connect to the DB server.

p.s*: Not looking forward to migrate the database to google cloud sql.

Comment: Without sharing code on how you are establishing your connection, it's hard to help. Please do edit your post to include this (redacting any possible private information, like IP's, users, passwords and so on)

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-third-party-databases#on_premises), you can either configure your internal network and firewall to give the database a public IP address or connect using a VPN.